# In objective C, how do I programmatically access a UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I have a tabbar application that nests a lot of uitableviewcontrollers and uiviewcontrollers.  What is the line of code that i would use to get a handle on a particular controller?

For example, let's say I want to grab the uitableviewcontroller which is currently the 3rd tab of the tab bar controller.  I am in the MyObject.h/m file which has the following code:

MyObject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@interface MyObject : NSObject

-(void) myfunction;

@end
```

MyObject.m

```
#import "MyObject.h"

@implementation MyObject



-(void) myfunction  {

    UITableViewController * mytvc = /*Some line of code*/;

}
@end
```

What do i replace `/*Some line of code*/` with such that mytvc is a variable that points to the uitableviewcontroller i'm interested in?

I am using XCode 4.2.  I have a storyboard that illustrates each of my uiviewcontrollers.  The Tabbar view controller was the first thing xcode made for me.  So I think that means it's the top of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is your root view controller, and you have access to your app delegate, you should be able to access your controller like this:

```
appDelegate.window.rootViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

`rootViewController.tabBarController.viewControllers` is an array of the root view controller for each tab. You can set the active view controller by setting `tabBarController.selectedViewController` or `tabBarController.selectedIndex`.

From the app delegate it's `self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController`. From a view controller it's `self.view.window.rootViewController.tabBarController`.

`[[self.view.window.rootViewController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] myFunction]` would access your function from another view controller. That is assuming your third tab is not a navigation controller.

If your tab has a navigation controller in it, then you have to add the navigation controller syntax on top of it. `[[[self.view.window.rootViewController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] navigationController].visibleViewController myFunction]` would be the full path. Looking at it now it seems a bit ridiculous.